# Apache Kafka's Streams API vs Spark Streaming

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I am comparing the throughput of spark streaming and Kafka streams. My results state that Kafka Streams has a higher throughput than Spark streaming. Is this correct? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Thanks

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spark-streaming-vs-kafka-stream-1

Comment: https://codelook.com/challenges-with-processing-data-in-real-time-using-conventional-big-data-solutions-bb602b33da0c

Answer (score 3):

No one streaming platform is universally faster than all others for every use case. Don't get fooled by benchmarketing results that compare apples to oranges (like Kafka Streams reading from a disk based source vs Spark Streaming reading from an in-memory source). You haven't posted your test but it is entirely possible that it represents a use case (and test environment) in which Kafka Streams is indeed faster.